# delete the images imagejpeg creates

Tags: php

Is it possible to delete the images that `imagejpeg` creates I have the images uploading to my Amazon S3 server but the files just pop up in the main directory on my server after its ran.

```
    $new_height = 120;
    $width = imagesx($originalImage);
    $height = imagesy($originalImage);
    $new_width = round(($width * $new_height) / $height);
    $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    $tmp_loc = 'uploads/thumb/';
    $tempfilename = tempnam($tmp_loc, $filename);
    imagejpeg($imageResized, $filename,100);
    imagedestroy($imageResized);
    imagedestroy($originalImage);
    unlink($tempfilename);
```

I tried `imagedestroy` and  `unlink($tempfilename);` but the file remains.

Comment: Where is your usage of `unlink()`?

Comment: Updated to where it was located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imagejpeg(...) should be outputting to $tempfilename rather than $filename, then you'd be unlinking the right file.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to open the variable `$tmp_loc`.

Look:

```
$tmp_loc = uploads/thumb/';
```

Correct:

```
$tmp_loc = 'uploads/thumb/';
```

Comment: sorry it actually has it, i just had to retype it as the spacing came out bizarre.